Spanish DateTime format issue
I am trying to read a Spanish DateTime value in PowerShell into a DateTime type variable but am unable to parse the string correctly.
The DateTime string is in the format: Lun Ene 01 18:01:57 2024. In English, this would be "Mon Jan 01 18:01:57 2024"
I have tried to parse this using the code:
$tempCreatedDate = "Lun Ene 01 18:01:57 2024"
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("es-ES")
$CreatedDate = [DateTime]::parseexact($tempCreatedDate, 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy', $culture)

but I receive the error:

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How can I fix this?

the format string you're using would be valid if the actual date to parse had a . after Lun and Ene

One thing to remember: when they use "Exact" in the ParseExact() name, they mean it. If the input string doesn't match the format string perfectly, the parse will fail.
I did some digging, and it looks like in this case you need the es-ES_tradnl culture:
$tempCreatedDate = "Lun Ene 01 18:01:57 2024"
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("es-ES_tradnl")
$CreatedDate = [DateTime]::parseexact($tempCreatedDate, 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy', $culture)

It's worth noting there's also a ParseExact() overload to allow an array of formats, so you can build format strings to handle both types if you expect to see both kinds of input. Unfortunately, there's not a similar overload to allow multiple cultures.

One thing you can do to help work through these issues is try outputting a preconstructed DateTime value in the desired format:
$d = new-object DateTime  2024, 1, 1, 18, 1, 57
$format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("es-ES")

$d.ToString($format, $culture)

In which case, you'd see this:

lu. ene. 01 18:01:57 2024

That lead me to look for how to parse Spanish date values without the extra periods, which is how I found the es-ES_tradnl culture option.

I was actually running: https://i.imgur.com/RlbjKDe.png to see which culture would output that string date. Weird that es-ES_tradnl isn't listed by GetCultures

Actually now that I'm testing, the code in your answer is not working in pwsh 7 (.NET) so this is some special culture in .NET Framework (pwsh 5.1)

@SantiagoSquarzon According to this, PS5.1 (Framework) is probably looking at the OS, while 7 (Core) bundles it own culture library (based on the International Components for Unicode Library). I get why they made the change (can't count on the OS anymore if you have to support rando linux distributions), but it would be nice to have missing options fall back to the OS.

Sorry I meant to say that es-ES_tradnl in .NET defaults to using the dots after day and month not that CultureInfo wasn't found but yeah, weird that the same CultureInfo outputs a different string for the same format string in .NET vs .NET Framework
